# How to run arrayformula to find overlapping days in a month given the start and end dates?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I am trying to get the number of days in each month based on the start and end date. However, my arrayformula is not working which I suspect it to be because of indirect. Would you be kind to enlighten me on how I can do so?

[image: view screenshot]

Descriptions for code:

column Q --> start date

column R --> end date

cell   U1--> value contains Mar ( in this case, I am trying to get the values for the month of March)

```
ARRAYFORMULA(SUMPRODUCT(--(TEXT(ROW(INDIRECT($Q$2:$Q & ":" & IF($R$2:$R="","",$R$2:$R))),"mmm")=$U$1)))
```

Comment: Post a screenshot of what your data looks like, and the results you expect. If the amount of data is non-trivial, post it as text which can be copy/pasted into a worksheet.

Comment: thanks! I have added in @RonRosenfeld

Comment: Given the data you posted, I don't understand how you develop the expected results you show for Feb and Mar.

Comment: So essentially you want to get the number of days between these two dates, for each month separately? @ShellyNA

Answer (score 1):

Try this in cell U2:

```
=max( 0, min($R2, eomonth(1 & U$1, 0)) - max($Q2, datevalue(1 & U$1)) + 1 )
```

Format the result cell as **Format > Number > Number** and copy it further as required.

I think this can be written as an array formula using `dmax()` and `dmin()` but it would probably be a bit complex, and thus left as an exercise for the reader.

See [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/153710/269219) for an explanation of how date and time values work in spreadsheets.